# The table "tablename" for active record class "TableClass" cannot be found in the database

Tags: php, mysql, caching, yii

I have a website that was running fine and all of sudden it has started to give this error. All those pages that require database connection are not working. I did NOT do anything on the website, checked all the configuration files and they have correct database connection.

I have read somewhere that yii caches metadata of tables and when cache if full then this error is caused? Is it so? If so how do I refresh the cache of metadata of tables. I know the function Yii::app()->schema->refresh() but where that function should be called? Also can I disable automatic caching of metadata of tables in Yii?

If the reason this problem is something else then can I know what is causing this issue?

Comment: The basic question, do you really have the table "tableName" on your database?

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling

```
Yii::app()->cache->flush();
```

to delete all cache in the application and make sure that caching is the problem and to allow your application to continue to work(if time is an important factor for you).

I cannot help you for tables metadata caching, unfortunately. Hopefully someone else will.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the Schema cache then you can use as below:

`Yii::app()->schema->getTable();
Yii::app()->schema->refresh();`

About your question as **When to call this function**. Whenever you think you have modified your table structure/schema like Adding/Deleting any new column etc, then you should run this command. 
As the changing of schema doesn't happen all the time, you can write this as a CLI Script within Yii and call this.

About you question as **can I disable automatic caching of metadata of tables in Yii?**.. Yes You can.
In your `main.php` configuration file, under the 'db' component, if you set the value as `'schemaCachingDuration' => 3600,` then you have enabled it. If you remove this, then you'll instruct not to cache the Schema.

Refer: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/final.deployment